# Append another dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to append a dropdown. What I'm trying to do is to simply add another dropdown with the help of a button. the dropdown should contain same items in it as the existing dropdown. so below is my code.

This is the jquery script for condition where user can't create more than 10 dropdown box.

```
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    if (counter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 dropdowns allowed");
        return false;
    }
    var newDDBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", +counter);
    newDDBoxDiv.after().html('<label>dropdown #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
        '<select type="text" name="dropdown' + counter +
        '" id="dropdown' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newDDoxDiv.appendTo("#mb");
    counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert("No more dropdown to remove");
        return false;
    }
    counter--;
    $("#tid" + counter).remove();
});
```

and below is my cshtml

```
  <div class="editor-field" id="mb">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MC, ViewBag.lCountry as SelectList, "--select--", new{@id="tid"})
```

Above code doesn't work. if anyone has any suggestion on how to accomplish it, please share.

edit: buttons are below

```
  <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton'>
```

Comment: Where is add and remove button? When you call drop-down its `select` tag not `input`

Comment: ah, i see. so i changed the input to select. but still. it shown an empty dropdown whenever i add new dropdown. i would like to add similar dropdown as i already have.

Comment: you want exact dropdown with same values?

Comment: dropdown with different, but yes, with the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i correcly understand your question you should use clone as

```
<select id="template">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<div id="test">
</div>
 <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
 <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addButton").click(function(){
var elements=$("select[id!='template']");
var newElement=$("#template").clone(true);
var count=elements.length;
if(count>8)
{
    alert('no more dropdowns');
}
else
{
    newElement.attr('id',count);//rename new element so that it refers to     distinguished object instead of cloned object
    $("#test").append(newElement);
}


});
});
</script>
```

obviously you have your DropDownList object in place of template object

Comment: Yes, thank you. this is what i was looking for. at least this is the closest. thanks so much. =)

Answer (score 2):

*Use*

```
//Create a div
var newDDBoxDiv = $('<div />',
{
    "id": "tid0" + (++counter)
});

//Append label
newDDBoxDiv.append('<label>dropdown #' + counter + ' : </label>');

//Clone select
var select = $("#tid").clone(true);

//Updated id
select.prop("id", "dropdown" + counter);

//Append cloned select to new div
newDDBoxDiv.append(select);

//Append to div
newDDoxDiv.appendTo("#mb");
```

Note: Update ID of your `select` to `tid0`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MC, ViewBag.lCountry as SelectList, "--select--", new{@id="tid0"})
```

Comment: In his code, he created a text box, not a drop down list. But I think this is his problem.

Comment: @ChauThan, Read his comment _ah, i see. so i changed the input to select. but still. it shown an empty dropdown whenever i add new dropdown._

Comment: Ok, this is the best solution for him.

Comment: Btw, please edit `"id" : ++counter`. I think it will not work in event remove.

Comment: @ChauThan, OP is using `counter` to keep track of no of elements.

Comment: `id` is this attribute of div element, right?
for example: `<div id='1'> </div>`
but in event remove we have: `$("#tid" + counter).remove();`
how about if i change
`"id" : "tid" + (++counter)`?

Comment: @Satpal, thanks for your time. ive been at this for hours. it still gives me a blank drop down instead of the drop down with same existing items.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...'

```
 var counter = 0;

 $('#addButton').click(function () {
     if (counter >= 10) {
         alert("Only 10 dropdowns allowed");
     } else {
         counter++;
         $(document.body).append('<div id="' + counter + '">' +
             '<label>dropdown #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
             '<select name="dropdown' + counter +
             '" id="dropdown' + counter + '">' +
         // Add your options here...
         '</select></div>');
     }
 });

 $('#removeButton').click(function () {
     if (counter <= 0) {
         alert("No dropdowns to remove");
     } else {
         $(document.body).find('div#' + counter).eq(0).remove();
         counter--;
     }
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/kvz2hj5a/)